# How to return from a child function?

Tags: node.js, xml

I have this function, it's responsible for getting a specific text of an element within an xml. But console.log gives me undefined every time i call the function. I get that the mistake is that i return to fs.readFile not to getTodayHoroscopes, but how can I fix it?

```
const getTodayHoroscope = (signNumber) => {
    fs.readFile('./horoscopy.xml', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('File read failed:', err);
        return;
        }
        try {
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "xml/html");
            horoscopeString = (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("today")[signNumber].textContent);
            result = horoscopeString
            return result;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error parsing JSON:', err);
        }
    console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `readFileSync`

```js
const getTodayHoroscope = (signNumber) => {
  try {
    const data = fs.readFileSync('./horoscopy.xml', 'utf8' )
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "xml/html");
    const horoscopeString = (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("today")[signNumber].textContent);
    return horoscopeString;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

2. `promise`

```js
const getTodayHoroscope =  (signNumber) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('./horoscopy.xml', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log('File read failed:', err);
          reject(err)
          return
      }
      try {
          parser = new DOMParser();
          xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "xml/html");
          horoscopeString = (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("today")[signNumber].textContent);
          result = horoscopeString
          resolve(result) ;
      } catch (err) {
          console.log('Error parsing JSON:', err);
          reject(err)
      }
  });
  })
}


(async () => {
  try {
    console.log(await getTodayHoroscope('xxx'))
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})();
```

Comment: [doc: promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[doc: await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: `fs` has native promise support. Don't roll your own. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#promises-api

Comment: Woah, this really is simpler, thanks :)